# Creating store with COG/GS GeoTIFF through REST API

Tags: geoserver, rest, cloud-optimized-geotiff

I am currently facing challenges with setting up a Cloud Optimized GeoTIFF (COG) store in GeoServer using a Python script. I have been successful in creating a COG store manually through the GeoServer web UI, but replicating this process programmatically has proven difficult.

Issue Description:
I'm using the GeoServer COG plugin to automate the creation of a COG store. My script successfully creates a coverage store, but it fails to apply the COG-specific settings correctly. When I go into the webui and check the checkbox for Cloud Optimized GeoTIFF (COG) and saves everything works as expected. I have tried with different xml settings like `<Cog>true</Cog> and <isCog>true</isCog>`

I'm thinking that the cog-plugin is not integrated into the GeoServer REST API, and this is why it fails.

What I've Tried:
I created a Python script that sends a POST request to GeoServer with XML data to create a coverage store.
I included elements in my XML similar to what I saw in the web UI and the curl response from a working COG store.
My script runs without errors, but the COG store doesn't seem to function as expected. It either doesn't recognize the COG settings or doesn't apply them correctly.

Specific Questions:

Are there specific XML configurations or properties I need to include in my script to properly set up a COG store?

Is there a difference in how the GeoServer REST API handles these settings compared to the web UI?

Additional Information:

- GeoServer version: [2.24.1]
- COG plugin version: [2.24]

Example of the script/XML payload:

```
    elif store_type == "coveragestore":
        # For raster data (e.g., GeoTIFF)
        data = f"""
            <coverageStore>
                <name>{store_name}</name>
                <type>{connection_parameters['type']}</type>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <workspace>{workspace}</workspace>
                <url>{connection_parameters['url']}</url>
                <useCachingStream>false</useCachingStream>
                <rangeReaderSettings>GS</rangeReaderSettings>
                <Cog>true</Cog>
                <isCog>true</isCog>
            </coverageStore>
            """
    else:
        print(f"Unsupported store type: {store_type}")
        return False

    print("URL:", f"{geoserver_url}/workspaces/{workspace}/{store_type}s")
    print("Headers:", headers)
    print("Data:", data)
    response = requests.post(f"{geoserver_url}/workspaces/{workspace}/{store_type}s", headers=headers, data=data, auth=auth)

    if response.status_code == 201:
        print(f"{store_type.capitalize()} '{store_name}' created successfully in workspace '{workspace}'.")
        return True
    else:
        print(f"Error creating {store_type} '{store_name}':", response.text)
        return False
Output:
Headers: {'Content-type': 'text/xml'}
Data: 
            <coverageStore>
                <name>test5</name>
                <type>GeoTIFF</type>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <workspace>test_workspace</workspace>
                <url>cog://gs://gcs-bucket/test_workspace/d2f4e6f5-ac19-420d-9469-fad1b8596906/products/d2f4e6f5-ac19-420d-9469-fad1b8596906_ortho.tif</url>
                <useCachingStream>false</useCachingStream>
                <rangeReaderSettings>GS</rangeReaderSettings>
                <Cog>true</Cog>
                <isCog>true</isCog>
            </coverageStore>
            
Coveragestore 'test5' created successfully in workspace 'test_workspace'.
```

Can you provide any guidance or insights you can provide on this matter?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, had to add CogSettings.Key to the xml, seems to working as intended now :)

```
data = f"""
                <coverageStore>
                    <name>{store_name}</name>
                    <type>{connection_parameters['type']}</type>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <workspace>{workspace}</workspace>
                    <url>{connection_parameters['url']}</url>
                    <metadata>
                        <entry key="CogSettings.Key">
                            <cogSettings>
                                <useCachingStream>false</useCachingStream>
                                <rangeReaderSettings>GS</rangeReaderSettings>
                            </cogSettings>
                        </entry>
                    </metadata>
                </coverageStore>
            """
```

Comment: Did you look at what a GET request returns for the store you created?